# How to Dynamically Evaluate Variable Java Expressions from JSON Data at Runtime?

Tags: java, json, dynamic, runtime, conditional-operator

I have a requirement to dynamically evaluate Java expressions provided as strings within my Java application. This expression is a ternary operator and it can change in the future as it's coming from a JSONObject. Additionally, the values of the variables used within the expressions will be provided at runtime. How can I achieve this dynamic evaluation in a Java application?

"value1 < 0 ? 3:5"

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I used groovy.lang.GroovyShell; As the code below shows I passed the String expression as well as a Map with key value pair containing the key matching the expressions variables and the value that will be generated at runtime. This fixed the issue for me.

```
public Object expressionEvaluator(String expression, Map<String,          

Integer> variables) {

var shell = new GroovyShell();
variables.forEach((name, value) -> shell.setVariable(name, value));

return shell.evaluate(expression);
}
}
```